# Dynamic drop down based on stock availability in database - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an e-commerce site and i have a 'size' drop down for customer's to choose their size. What i want is for the drop down to only display sizes that are available as per the 'stock' value held in the database.

Does anyone have experience doing this or have any insights?

**sizes table within schema**

```
create_table "sizes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "stock"
    t.string   "size"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Size.rb**

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :product
end
```

**Order_Product.rb**

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :size
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :order_products
    has_many :orders, through: :order_products
    has_many :sizes
end
```

**product/show.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for :basket, url: product_basket_path(@product), remote: true do |f| %>

<%= f.input :quantity, as: :select, collection: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], selected: 1, required: false %>

<%= f.input :size, as: :select, collection: @product.sizes, selected: 0, required: false %>

<%= f.button :submit, "Add to basket" %>

<% end %>
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a scope to your sizes model, and use this to populate the select field.

Scope:

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product

  scope :in_stock, where('stock > 0')

end
```

Select field:

```
<%= f.input :size, as: :select, collection: @product.sizes.in_stock, selected: 0, required: false %>
```

Using a scope rather than filtering in the view lets you re-use the in_stock scope elsewhere, and to perform an SQL query rather than loading all the records and iterating through them all.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas, this sounds like the better of the two. However, when i reduce the stock of 'large' to 0 and view the drop down, it displays all sizes including 'large' but also 'small' and 'medium' again i.e. 'small' 'medium' 'large' 'small' medium'. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: So i think the problem here is that in my sizes table, i have other products with sizes 'small' 'medium' and 'large' so it is displaying those in the drop down as well. Unsure what the solution is here?

Comment: If you do @product.sizes.in_stock, it should only be the sizes related to that product. If multiple are appearing, there must be multiple identical sizes per product. How about adding a uniqueness validation on sizes, scoped to the product ID?

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Douglas. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: the problem, it seems, was that by having the scope within the Size model all sizes were being displayed regardless of product. To fix i created a method in the product model that replicates the scope functionality as suggested by Douglas

Comment: Something else going wrong there then. This is standard ActiveRecord stuff. Good to hear you got your problem fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood what you want to do exactly; You should be able to select all available size values with `pluck` like this:

```
@product.sizes.where('stock >= 1').pluck(:size, :id)
```

Edit: See Douglas F Shearer's post, the scope is a much more elegant solution than just putting Ruby code in your views!

Comment: Thanks @Rudolf. This works as expected until i go to view my basket. Problem being that the `:size` is being sent through as a string rather than the id for the size as my controller expects. And changing `:size` to `:id` fixes the issue but then the drop down displays the id rather than the human readable string. Trying to figure out a solution??

Comment: Ah, now I get it! I adjusted the answer, see above.

Comment: Thanks @Rudolf thought i'd tried that but obviously not!

Comment: So, this was the solution? If you accept it as the correct answer, I will include the suggestion of Douglas and write it as a scope!

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @Douglas's answer, i found the following to work.

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :order_products
    has_many :orders, through: :order_products
    has_many :sizes

    def in_stock
        self.sizes.where('stock > 0')
    end
end
```

**product/show.html.erb**

```
<%= f.input :size, as: :select, collection: @product.in_stock, selected: 0, required: false %>
```

Thanks for all help!